Angular loop of components, changing one of them doesn't trigger change event into child component
I have Angular app with child components in loop:
<ng-container *ngFor="let component of components; let i = index">
  <component [component]="component"></component>
</ng-container>

into parent component during some actions I do:
let component = this.components.find(x => x.key === item.key);
component!.value = data;

and after code above I'm waiting in child component that change action will be executed:
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  console.log('change');
  console.log(changes);
}

but nothing was changed, am I doing something wrong? Or how can I fix that?

If the variable going into @Input is a primitive type number, string, boolean, etc then it will work.
But for non primitive types like array or object it is stored as reference in memory, if you change the interal values, that will not change the reference. So we need to manually update the reference using array/object destructuring (creates a new memory reference) so that angular detects the change in memory ref and runs ngOnChanges.
let componentIndex = this.components.findIndex(x => x.key === item.key);
if(componentIndex > -1) {
    const component = this.components[componentIndex];
    component!.value = data;
    this.components[componentIndex] = { ...component }; // <- changed here!
}


unfortunately it doesn't work for me

@A.Gladkiy try now, my mistake, we need to update the reference of the inner object not the array.
